# How to define DifferentIndividuals in SWRL rule in protege

Tags: protege, swrl

I have a questioin about how to define two different idividuals in SWRQL. Here is an example.
If B isSonOf A;
If C isSonOf A;
Then B and C are brothers.
Here is the SWRL rule:
isSunOf(?BB, ?AA) ^ isSunOf(?CC, ?AA) -> isBrotherOf(?BB, ?CC)

I found in the reasoned results, B is isBrotherOf B himself. How to avoid this problem?

Thank you!
Best regards,
Yang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `differentFrom(?a, ?b)` i.e.:

`isSonOf(?a, ?c) ^ isSonOf(?b, ?c) ^ differentFrom(?a, ?b) -> isBrotherOf(?a, ?b)`

Comment: it should be mentioned that it works only if `owl:differentFrom` is set explicitly in the ontology given that there is no Unique Names Assumption in OWL and the rule won't match otherwise